# C# Regex to validate string

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex pattern:

```
"[A-Z]{6,6}[A-Z2-9][A-NP-Z0-9]([A-Z0-9]{3,3}){0,1}"
```

and I want to validate a string with the following conditions

- allow only alphanumeric characters
- has length of only 8 or 11
- first 6 characters must all be uppercase letters

However, the above pattern is not working. What needs to be changed?

Comment: Try http://Regexhero.net its good tool for testing your expressions.

Comment: Try this one :  (?:[a-zA-Z]{8,11}\d+)

Comment: If you want more accurate answer. you should paste some examples.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use following regular expression:

```
^[A-Z]{6}[A-Za-z0-9]{2}([A-Za-z0-9]{3})?$
```

---

First 6 characters must all be uppercase letters (`^` means that following pattern should match at the start of the string):

```
^[A-Z]{6}
```

Now there should be 2 or 5 more alphanumeric characters; 2 alphanumeric chracters should come anyway:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{2}
```

and 3 after that is optional (`?`: 0 or 1 match of the preceding pattern, `$` means that preceding pattern should match at the end of the string):

```
([A-Za-z0-9]{3})?$
```

Using `^` and `$` together (`^PATTERN$`), the pattern should match the whole string instead of the substring.

Comment: Nice detailed explanation. Very pedagogical! :) For completeness, you might add that `^` means that that part of the patterns must be at the start of the target string (anchored to it's start), and that `$` anchors the other end to the end of the string in the same way, so that this pattern _must_ represent the _whole_ target string.

Comment: @Kjartan, Thank you for the advice. I added an explanation about `^`, `$`.

Answer (score 1):

The expression should be:

```
^[A-Z]{6}([A-Za-z0-9]{2}|[A-Za-z0-9]{5})$
```